# Windows 10 - Notifications Not Appearing

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I have notifications appearing in the sidebar

[image]
However, nothing pops up on my screen - how do I fix this?

Comment: Go to PC Settings > System > Notifications & actions. Ensure that all options are On and that the Lightshot app is in the list and is marked as On.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Focus Assist option is enabled. This option is to avoid getting interrupted by notification pop-ups. Windows sometimes proposes to turn it on, when running games for instance.

In your Notification panel, click the Focus Assist button -- it is the button with half moon icon in your screenshot. There are 3 modes: Off, Priority and Alarms. Click to cycle until it says Off.